# Strange transport layer port number during nfs conversation

Tags: nfs, automount, autofs

I use autofs to mount nfs shares, autofses part works well, I can reach the leaf folders, but when I try to access that folder the following packet exchange takes place and my shell stacks, it  drops

```
[gm-web01]/net/arkive03/mnt/mfs> cd mfsbackup
-bash: cd: mfsbackup: No such file or directory
```

message after about a minute. Look at last two lines, how port number can be higher then normal transport layer range?

```
[arkive03]~> tcpdump -i em1 -nn host 10.24.20.163
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on em1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:33:48.598351 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [S], seq 2431214407, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 77231839 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:33:48.598381 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [S.], seq 1732090298, ack 2431214408, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2997710933 ecr 77231839,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:33:48.602006 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231840 ecr 2997710933], length 0
11:33:48.602043 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231840 ecr 2997710933], length 44
11:33:48.602054 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [.], ack 45, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710934 ecr 77231840], length 0
11:33:48.602288 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [P.], seq 1:29, ack 45, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710934 ecr 77231840], length 28
11:33:48.605756 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [.], ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231841 ecr 2997710934], length 0
11:33:48.605826 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [P.], seq 45:105, ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231841 ecr 2997710934], length 60
11:33:48.606038 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [P.], seq 29:61, ack 105, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710935 ecr 77231841], length 32
11:33:48.609504 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [S], seq 1293458899, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 77231842 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:33:48.609534 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.46403: Flags [S.], seq 2805863182, ack 1293458900, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2997710935 ecr 77231842,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:33:48.612993 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231842 ecr 2997710935], length 0
11:33:48.613030 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231842 ecr 2997710935], length 44: NFS request xid 916703790  null
11:33:48.613042 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.46403: Flags [.], ack 45, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710936 ecr 77231842], length 0
11:33:48.613149 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.46403: Flags [P.], seq 1:29, ack 45, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710936 ecr 77231842], length 28: NFS reply xid 916703790 reply ok 24 null
11:33:48.616331 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [.], ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231843 ecr 2997710936], length 0
11:33:48.616402 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [P.], seq 105:149, ack 61, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231843 ecr 2997710935], length 44
11:33:48.616600 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [P.], seq 61:89, ack 149, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710937 ecr 77231843], length 28
11:33:48.620262 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [P.], seq 149:209, ack 89, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231844 ecr 2997710937], length 60
11:33:48.620457 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [P.], seq 89:121, ack 209, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710938 ecr 77231844], length 32
11:33:48.624021 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [P.], seq 45:89, ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231845 ecr 2997710936], length 44: NFS request xid 1081853030  null
11:33:48.624103 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.46403: Flags [P.], seq 29:57, ack 89, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710939 ecr 77231845], length 28: NFS reply xid 1081853030 reply ok 24 null
11:33:48.627318 IP 10.24.20.163.53809 > 10.44.20.137.111: UDP, length 40
11:33:48.627507 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.53809: UDP, length 24
11:33:48.627617 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [F.], seq 89, ack 57, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231846 ecr 2997710939], length 0
11:33:48.627687 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.46403: Flags [F.], seq 57, ack 90, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710940 ecr 77231846], length 0
11:33:48.627706 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [F.], seq 209, ack 121, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231846 ecr 2997710938], length 0
11:33:48.627798 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.55219: Flags [F.], seq 121, ack 210, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2997710940 ecr 77231846], length 0
11:33:48.629818 IP 10.24.20.163.53809 > 10.44.20.137.111: UDP, length 56
11:33:48.630039 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.53809: UDP, length 28
11:33:48.631031 IP 10.24.20.163.46403 > 10.44.20.137.2049: Flags [.], ack 58, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231847 ecr 2997710940], length 0
11:33:48.631111 IP 10.24.20.163.55219 > 10.44.20.137.111: Flags [.], ack 122, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 77231847 ecr 2997710940], length 0
11:33:48.632826 IP 10.24.20.163.2073489439 > 10.44.20.137.2049: 40 null
11:33:48.632921 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.2073489439: reply ok 24 null
11:33:48.635617 IP 10.24.20.163.53809 > 10.44.20.137.111: UDP, length 40
11:33:48.635807 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.53809: UDP, length 24
11:33:48.638213 IP 10.24.20.163.53809 > 10.44.20.137.111: UDP, length 56
11:33:48.638404 IP 10.44.20.137.111 > 10.24.20.163.53809: UDP, length 28
11:33:48.641185 IP 10.24.20.163.**217782617** > 10.44.20.137.2049: 40 null
11:33:48.641280 IP 10.44.20.137.2049 > 10.24.20.163.**217782617**: reply ok 24 null
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, that's not a TCP nor UDP port number; **it's the RPC transaction ID.** (See `print-nfs.c:nfsreply_print` in tcpdump sources.)

tcpdump sometimes tends to use very terse output; consider using `-v` or tshark instead.